# How do I compare objects based on their location on a line

Tags: java

i am trying to write a compare to method that will do this.

```
// If a and b lie on the same horizontal line, 
//    then a < b when a is to the left of b
// Otherwise, a < b when a is below b
```

i dnt really know how to do this, usually i just compare if a>b return +ve int and -ve int if less than or 0 for equal.

My solution from your suggestions.........

i used ideas form Jim Blackler, Ralph and Peter Lawrey and came up with this. it works sorry i was a little confused and did not think of the  Cartesian cordinates thanks Aasmund Eldhuset, this is my final compare method.. and it works

class Lexicographical implements Comparator{
    //This needs to be rewritten so...
    // If a and b lie on the same horizontal line, 
    //    then a < b when a is to the left of b
    // Otherwise, a < b when a is below b
    public int compare(Point a, Point b)
    {
        if (a.y == b.y) // y axis are the same(same line)
        {
              if(a.x < b.x)// to the left of b(on the x axis)
                  return -1;
              else
                  return 1;// to the right of b
        } 
        else if(a.y < b.y)// y axis are not the same(below not same line)
        {
                return -1;

```
    }
    else 
        return 0;
}
```

}

Comment: Line of what? How do you store the line in which an object is? Without knowing it in advance how can we answer?

Comment: what do you mean by "on the same line" are they in an array? is line a member of those object?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean like

```
class Point implements Comparable<Point> {
  double x,y;

  public int compareTo(Point b) {
      // If a and b lie on the same horizontal line, 
      if (y == b.y)
      //    then a < b when a is to the left of b
          return x < b.x ? -1 : x > b.x ? +1 : 0;
      // Otherwise, a < b when a is below b
      return y < b.y ? -1 : y > b.y ? +1 : 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: `implements Comparable<Point>` ?

Comment: @Dave Costa, a sensible addition, but not a requirement. I will add now. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a class attribute for whatever types a and b are that you can compareTo.  It's easy once you starting thinking more concretely.

What are the types for a and b?

Answer (score 0):

```
if (a.y == b.y) {
  return a.x < b.x;
} else {
  return a.y < b.y;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the text, it sounds like `a` and `b` are Cartesian coordinates (each with an *x* and a *y* value). Do you have a class that represents coordinates? If not, you should make one, and the compare method should take two instances of that class, and you can use their *x* and *y* values to determine whether they are on the same horizontal line, or which one is to the left of the other.

Answer (score 0):

One way to implement a compare Method in java is the [Comparable Interface](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html)

It has only one method `int compareTo(T o)`. This method compares this object (*the object on which the method is invoked*) with the specified object (*b*). Returns a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as this object is less than, equal to, or greater than the specified object.

Assume the object is of class Pseudo (*because it is only pseudo code*), then the compare method should looks like this.

```
class Pseudo implements Comparable<Pseudo> {

   @Override
   int compareTo(Pseudo b) {

     if (this and b lie on the same horizontal line) {
        if (this is to the left of b) {
           return -1;
        } else {
          return 1;
        }
      } else {
         if (this is to the below of b) {
           return -1;
         } else {
            return 1;
         }
      }
   }
}
```